# how to construct an active high pass filter on breadboard

Tags: analog, filter, control

i am going to have an experiment on active high pass filters and i would like someone to tell me how could i construct / carry the experiment please i don't want be embarrassed.

so tell me please what equipment/device are we going to use and the procedure in general.

Regards

Comment: What cut-off frequency are you trying to get? That will help us know whether building it on a breadboard might work or not.

Comment: What sort of stuff do you have at your disposal?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by high-pass (kilohertz? megahertz? Gigahertz?) and what you mean by breadboard (white plastic object with lotsa-holes - better be kilohertz)

In general, keep wires short and tidy, but if dealing with the white plastic lotsa-holes type, short wires will only help a little at higher frequencies, where the vast amounts of stray capacitance will significantly impede the function of the filter - at which point you might want to move to a prototype that's built by soldering things onto (or above - look for "dead-bug" examples) a circuit board with a ground plane underlying everything. Sometimes you can cut a few islands into the copper coated board, or you can add separate islands or strips on top of the copper-coated board.